# Google Charts: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hooks' of undefined at Object.success .

Tags: csv, hook

Hi guys really struggling here. trying to use a csv file and Google Chart API to display the csv but keeps error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hooks' of undefined at Object.success". Have been searching everywhere but can find a solution." Check out my code below.

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript"> // Reads in the csv file
    /*$(function() { // grab the CSV 
        $.get("ifr.csv", function(csvString) { // display the contents of the CSV 
        $("#chart").html(csvString); }); });*/

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); 
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() { // grab the CSV 
            $.get("ifr.csv", function(csvString) {
                var arrayData = $.csv2Arrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

                var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); view.setColumns([0,1]);

                var options = { title: "Perfume Reports", hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max}, vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max}, legend: 'none' };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart')); chart.draw(view, options); }); }

    </script> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="chart"> </div> 
</body>
```

@endsection

Comment: Should also have mentioned that i am running it off XAMPP. i just created a single project within my HTDOCS and the exact same script run without any errors.

Comment: Not solved but must be chrome specific?? tried the program in firefox and works.